# Ksh script: Run bash-like character substitute: ${@/.txt/}

Tags: regex, linux, ksh

I have a ksh script that has to remain so (some of the programs it runs insist on being ksh).  I want to take the input argument "test.txt" and remove the last 4 characters or find and replace the ".txt" with nothing.

In bash I would do

```
NewVar=${@/.txt/}
```

This doesn't work in ksh though.  How can I get rid of the .txt in ksh? I tried

```
bash -c 'NewVar=${@/.txt/}'
```

but it didn't work the $@ variable into this newly created shell.

Thanks,

Dan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not use [basename](http://linux.die.net/man/1/basename)?

Answer (score 0):

ksh won't let you do it with $@, but if you assign it to a temporary variable, you can do it without spawning another proc with

```
tmp=$@
newvar=${tmp%.txt}
```